# Android EditText or possibly OnClickEvent issue

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I've read through tons of questions and was unable to find an answer that worked. Anyway, I'm new to android/java programming, and can't get my button onClick to get my EditText contents and use them accordingly(?) I think is my problem, heres my code

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Fittings extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GoButton);
    go.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText circum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CtoD);
    int C = Integer.parseInt(circum.getText().toString());
    TextView CtoDAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CtoDAnswer);      
    CtoDAnswer.setText((int) (C * 0.3183));

}
```

}

Comment: just try go.setOnClickListener(Fittings.this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `CtoDAnswer.setText((int) (C * 0.3183));`, which does not add a string with that number, but adds a resource with that ID to it. Since you do not have a string resource c*0.3183, you won't get the right answer.

Use `CtoDAnswer.setText(Integer.toString(C * 0.3183));`

See the API reference for that method here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29

---

As a second comment (and this is unrelated to your problem, but an advise on good practices and app efficiency): Do not inflate the resource every time you click on the button, but inflate it inside onCreate and use a class field to store it. I.e.:

```
EditText circum;
// 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
circum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CtoD);
//
public void onClick(View v) {
    int C = Integer.parseInt(circum.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Just to clarify, 1) is probably why you're not getting the right text to display in your EditText.

Comment: @dmon you're right, it was not clear that the first part was the direct answer to the problem. I edited it to make it more obvious. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I'll try to mix this all together hence the still learning :P can int have decimals? i thought that might have been part of the problem and i got everything to work by:

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText circum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CtoD);
    double C = Integer.parseInt(circum.getText().toString());
    TextView CtoDAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CtoDAnswer);
    double answer = (C * 0.3183);
    CtoDAnswer.setText(": " + answer);

Comment: @Scott yes, that should work. Casting to int will remove all decimals (`int` means *integer*). Adding the colon inside quotes makes the whole argument a String, and thus it works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `@Override` to your method `onClick(View v )`  like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    //do stuff 
    EditText circum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CtoD);
    int C = Integer.parseInt(circum.getText().toString());
    TextView CtoDAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CtoDAnswer);      
    CtoDAnswer.setText(Integer.toString(C * 0.3183));//this will Fix the problem
    String txtCentent = myEditText.getText():
    Log.i("Content EditText"," Content = "+txtContent);
}
```

**BEST PRACTICE :**

It will be better if you get all your Views in you method `onCreate`, because every time you click on the button, you try to find Views By ID, so it will be some kind of repeating.

Comment: Adding the @Override annotation is a good practice, but it's optional. It won't change the outcome of the method.

Comment: i i've the sameproblem, i'm programming an app , and i didn't add @Override to my method , and it didn't work until i add it :) , the problem in his Code is he tried to put an int into his EditText , see my Edit

Comment: If the button isnt always used when the app is opened would it be better to leave the views inside the button instead of onCreate? i would think its about 50/50 of the chances of the button getting used

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText circum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CtoD);
    double C = Integer.parseInt(circum.getText().toString());
    TextView CtoDAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CtoDAnswer);      
    double answer = (C * 0.3183);
    CtoDAnswer.setText(": " + answer);
```

Was what I came up with, but from the suggestions some stuff will be moved, thanks!